# groupby comma-separated values in single DataFrame column python/pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

As an example, let's say I have a python pandas DataFrame that is the following:

```
#  PERSON  THINGS
0  Joe     Candy Corn, Popsicles
1  Jane    Popsicles
2  John    Candy Corn, Ice Packs
3  Lefty   Ice Packs, Hot Dogs
```

I would like to use the pandas *groupby* functionality to have the following output:

```
THINGS        COUNT
Candy Corn    2
Popsicles     2
Ice Packs     2
Hot Dogs      1
```

I generally understand the following *groupby* command:

```
df.groupby(['THINGS']).count()
```

But the output is not by individual item, but by the entire string. I think I understand why this is, but it's not clear to me how to best approach the problem to get the desired output instead of the following:

```
THINGS                  PERSON
Candy Corn, Ice Packs   1
Candy Corn, Popsicles   1
Ice Packs, Hot Dogs     1
Popsicles               1
```

Does pandas have a function like the *LIKE* in SQL, or am I thinking about how to do this wrong in pandas?

Any assistance appreciated.

Comment: It'd be super useful to share what you have written to get as far as you have.

Comment: @HackSaw -- I can certainly try. Do you mean the larger problem I'm trying to solve or the code itself to get to the point of asking the question (or something else?) I'm new here and want to make sure I understand the question (and where best to put it). Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a series by splitting words, and use `value_counts`

```
In [292]: pd.Series(df.THINGS.str.cat(sep=', ').split(', ')).value_counts()
Out[292]:
Popsicles     2
Ice Packs     2
Candy Corn    2
Hot Dogs      1
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to split `THINGS` by `,` and flatten the series and count values.

```
pd.Series([item.strip() for sublist in df['THINGS'].str.split(',') for item in sublist]).value_counts()
```

Output:

```
Candy Corn    2
Popsicles     2
Ice Packs     2
Hot Dogs      1
dtype: int64
```